# MySQL Query returning strange values

Tags: php, mysql

The query is supposed to do the following:

> Obtain the question and associated answers based on the identification number of the question. (In this case the identification number is called `account_id`. Order them so that each question (and it's appropriate answers) are lined up in order.

The query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM quiz_questions q
 JOIN quiz_answers a
    ON q.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE q.account_id = 1840979156127491
ORDER BY q.question_id
ASC LIMIT 5
```

The `quiz_questions` table and contents:
[image]

The `quiz_answers` table and contents:
[image]

Strange altered results:[image]

As you can see where the question_id is ordered, all of the values are `1` however, the other question_id field (These fields match if you look at the previous data) are representing two, like they should. Also, even though the question (with the id of 2) is displayed in the secondary question_id field, the text for the question still belongs to question 1: (`do you like waffles`) apposed to (`do you like pancakes`).

What is causing these results? Here's what the expected results should look like: (Ignoring duplicate fields).

```
+------------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------+----------------------+---------+
|    account_id    | question_id |       question       | answer_id |        answer        | correct |
+------------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------+----------------------+---------+
| 1840979156127491 |           1 | Do you like waffles  |         1 | Yes i like waffles   |       1 |
| 1840979156127491 |           1 | Do you like waffles  |         5 | I kinda like waffles |       1 |
| 1840979156127491 |           1 | Do you like waffles  |         6 | Not at all           |       0 |
| 1840979156127491 |           2 | Do you like pancakes |         7 | Yes                  |       1 |
| 1840979156127491 |           2 | Do you like pancakes |         8 | No           |       0 |
+------------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------+----------------------+---------+
```

Comment: The name of your table as well as the way you put the question, it seems you are trying to solve a homework question. If you, please state it clearly and show more of what you (yourself) have tried so far.

Comment: @luksch - This has nothing to do with homework, it was just an example. I'm not even in school. Well, I've put this entire query together, gone through the only few join tutorials on YouTube that exist. Did a few searches on jumbled SQL results. Tried changing the sorting, attempted to use a group by which destroyed the entire structure. Can't sort by the question text because multiple users can have the same question.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for clearing that up. I am sure you will find help here.

Comment: Come on. Engage brain for a minute. Coffee might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join by `account_id` and also `question_id`

```
SELECT * FROM `quiz_questions`
INNER JOIN `quiz_answers` 
ON `quiz_questions`.`account_id` = `quiz_answers`.`account_id`
  AND `quiz_questions`.`question_id` = `quiz_answers`.`question_id`
WHERE `quiz_questions`.`account_id` = '1840979156127491'
ORDER BY `quiz_questions`.`question_id`
ASC LIMIT 5
```